# Read multiple lines from subprocess.Popen.stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

I modified the source code from Fred Lundh's Python Standard Library.
The original source uses popen2 to communicate to subprocess, but I changed it to use subprocess.Popen() as follows.

```
import subprocess
import string

class Chess:
    "Interface class for chesstool-compatible programs"

    def __init__(self, engine = "/opt/local/bin/gnuchess"):
        proc=subprocess.Popen([engine],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.fin, self.fout = proc.stdin, proc.stdout

        s = self.fout.readline() <--
        print s
        if not s.startswith("GNU Chess"):
            raise IOError, "incompatible chess program"

    def move(self, move):
        ...
        my = self.fout.readline() <--
        ...

    def quit(self):
        self.fin.write("quit\n")
        self.fin.flush()

g = Chess()
print g.move("a2a4")
print g.move("b2b3")
g.quit()
```

It seems to run OK, but the gnuchess prints out multiple lines of messages as follows, but with self.fout.readline() it only shows one line.

```
Thinking...
... 
R N B Q K B N R
```

How do I get multiple lines of message? readlines() method doesn't seem to work.

#### ADDED

I tested the code from movieyoda, but it doesn't work. 
I think it's just correct that only readline() should work, not readlines() and read(), as one doesn't know when to stop reading except for the readline().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To interact with gnuchess, I'd use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html).

```
import pexpect
import sys
game = pexpect.spawn('/usr/games/gnuchess')
# Echo output to stdout
game.logfile = sys.stdout
game.expect('White')
game.sendline('a2a4')
game.expect('White')
game.sendline('b2b3')
game.expect('White')
game.sendline('quit')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just read it's output as it arrives. When the process dies, the subprocess module will take care of cleaning things up for you. You could do something like this -

```
l = list()
while True:
    data = proc.stdout.read(4096)
    if not data:
        break
    l.append(data)
file_data = ''.join(l)
```

All of this is a replacement for `self.fout.readline()`. Have not tried it. But should handle multiple lines.